# SolrSearchIndex: No matching constructor was found

Tags: sxa, solr

What I have:
Under IIS: I have Sitecore 9.0.2 XP0 with SXA 1.7 and SOLR for indexing working fine.

Under Visual Studio: I have Habitat Solution downloaded from https://codeload.github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.HabitatHome.Platform/zip/9.0.2.2
The solution gets build and published using gulp successfully.

Upon successfully publishing, I browsed the Sitecore client and it broke

## Error:

[image]

Stack trace:
[image]

Error in the log file:

> Could not find constructor in ReflectionUtil.CreateObject: Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Providers.Solr.SolrSearchIndex. The constructor parameters may not match or it may be an abstract class.

What I have checked:

- Name of SOLR cores
- Disabled `Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrCloud.SwitchOnRebuild.config.example`
- The version of `Sitecore.Kernel.dll` under `IIS`(before publishing code) and under Visual Studio to be same.

I have no luck till now.

Can you please help me, where to luck further for this?

Any suggestion will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: My guess is that you have a partial index definition (probably because the index definition config file is disabled but another patch file that configures that index is enabled). Can you load `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` and review your indexes?  Add them to your question for future troubleshooting, too.

Comment: @DanSinclair: On the show config page also, i am getting the same error. So, not able to  access the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because I missed to create the SOLR cores for SXA after the installation.

Answer (score 4):

1)
The root cause of your problem may be that you are not using proper version of SXA with your version of Sitecore.

For Sitecore 9 Update 2 (Sitecore 9.0.2) you should have SXA 1.7 Update 1 (SXA 1.7.1) installed.

Take a look on official compatibility matrix here:
https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/180187

2)
**For Habitat actually you don't need to install SXA**. There is another Sitecore repo called [HabitatHome.Platform](https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.HabitatHome.Platform) where SXA is needed.

3)
Also make sure you are using correct version of Habitat that is compatible with your version of Sitecore. It should be version / release v1.6 of Habitat in your case.

Get code from here:
https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/releases/tag/v1.6

4)
Follow Getting started for your particular version of Habitat to install all proper prerequisites:
https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/blob/v1.6/docs/01-Getting-Started.md

Comment: Sorry. Got to know of the actual cause quite late.